# How to get INNER JOIN result from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have the three MySql tables :

1. **table_fonts**

   - font_id (int)
   - font_name (varchar)
2. **table_charsets**

   - charset_id (int)
   - charset_name (varchar) (examples: 1=latin, 2=greek, and so on)
3. **table_charsets_by_font**

   - font_id (int)
   - charset_id (int)

I am having trouble into creating my INNER JOIN query to obtain a list with all charsets (*table_charsets.charset_name*) listed in columns, with *a value of 1* if existing, or *a value of 0* if not existing **— aka a TINYINT —**, like this :

```
font_id | font_name | charset_id1 | charset_id1_existing | charset_id2 | charset_id2_existing ... and so on
```

For example :

```
1 | Arial           | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 ... and so on
2 | Arial Black     | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 ... and so on
3 | Times New Roman | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 ... and so on
```

So far, all my attempts have failed. Could someone point me to the right direction ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT tf.font_id, tf.font_name, tcf.font_id, tc.charset_name, tcf.font_id, tcf.charset_id  
FROM table_fonts tf 
INNER JOIN table_charsets_by_font tcf ON tcf.font_id=tf.font_id
INNER JOIN table_charsets tc ON tc.charset_id=tcf.charset_id
WHERE tc.charset_name='latin';
```

Comment: Hi @pankaj-kumar, thanks to proposing me a classic INNER JOIN which is not exactly what I was needing...

Comment: Hi Alex may I get some sample data of tables so that classic INNER JOIN can be converted into needful join....